# Can decorator decorate a recursive function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, decorator

I wanted to see difference of time cost between two ways to calculate Fibonacci sequence：
First, I created a decorator add "output time cost" function to a function:

```
def time_cost(func):
    def wed(n):
        start = time.time()
        func(n)
        stop = time.time()
        print(stop-start)
    return wed
```

Then I wrote the first function:

```
@time_cost
def DP_F(n):
    f = [1,1]
    while len(f)<n:
    f.append(f[len(f)-1]+f[len(f)-2])
    return f
```

It worked well

```
>>> DP_F(10)
0.0
>>> DP_F(100)
0.0
>>> DP_F(10000)
0.007944107055664062
```

But something wrong happened when I create the second function with decorator:

```
@time_cost
def R_F(n):
    if n<=2:
        return 1
    else:
        return R_F(n-1)+R_F(n-2)
```

Raised error saying some of the output may missed

```
>>> R_F(10)
0.0
0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#44>", line 1, in <module>
    R_F(10)
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 4, in wed
    func(n)
  File "<pyshell#43>", line 8, in R_F
    return R_F(n-1)+R_F(n-2)
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 4, in wed
    func(n)
  File "<pyshell#43>", line 8, in R_F
    return R_F(n-1)+R_F(n-2)
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 4, in wed
    func(n)
  File "<pyshell#43>", line 8, in R_F
    return R_F(n-1)+R_F(n-2)
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 4, in wed
    func(n)
  File "<pyshell#43>", line 8, in R_F
    return R_F(n-1)+R_F(n-2)
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 4, in wed
    func(n)
  File "<pyshell#43>", line 8, in R_F
    return R_F(n-1)+R_F(n-2)
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 4, in wed
    func(n)
  File "<pyshell#43>", line 8, in R_F
    return R_F(n-1)+R_F(n-2)
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 4, in wed
    func(n)
  File "<pyshell#43>", line 8, in R_F
    return R_F(n-1)+R_F(n-2)
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 4, in wed
    func(n)
  File "<pyshell#43>", line 8, in R_F
    return R_F(n-1)+R_F(n-2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

So Python decorator cannot decorate recursive function?

Comment: Your wrapper returns `None`

Comment: Inside `wed`, you called `func(n)` (which would be any of `DP_F` and `R_F` in this example) without capturing and returning that result.  Default return value becomes `None`, explaining the error.  It isn't because Python decorators cannot decorate recursive functions.

Comment: You can, but it's the *decorated* function that gets called repeatedly, not the original function. Every "recursive" call will call `wed`, which starts a new timer and executes a new `print` statement. Something like this is better handled with a context manager than a decorator.

Answer (score 4):

The immediate issue is that `wed` doesn't return the return value of `func`. That's easy to fix.

```
def time_cost(func):
    def wed(n):
        start = time.time()
        n = func(n)
        stop = time.time()
        print(stop-start)
        return n
    return wed
```

However, now look what happens when you call `R_F(3)`.

```
>>> R_F(3)
9.5367431640625e-07
1.1920928955078125e-06
0.0001671314239501953
2
```

You get *3* times: one per recursive call. This is because the original function calls whatever `R_F` is bound to, which now is the the function `wed`, not the actual Fibonacci function.

Something like this is better handled using a context manager.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def time_cost():
    start = time.time()
    yield
    stop = time.time()
    print(stop - start)

with time_cost():
    R_F(3)
```

---

### A digression

In some sense, Python doesn't have recursive functions. A function cannot call itself, but rather only some function bound to the name you *expect* will refer to your function. Call it "cooperative recursion".

For example, consider the standard example of a recursive function, the factorial.

```
def fact(x):
     return 1 if x == 0 else x * fact(x-1)
```

We can easily break this by rebinding the name `fact`.

```
g = fact  # save a reference to the original function
def fact(x):
   print("Broken")
   return 0
```

Now `g(3)` prints `Broken` and returns 0, because it will try to call whatever `fact` is bound to *now*, not what `fact` was bound to before you redefined it.

If you want a "safe" recursive function, you would have to define it in terms of a private recursive helper.

```
def fact(x):
    def helper(x):
        return 1 if x == 0 else x * helper(x - 1)
    return helper(x)
```

Now you can safely decorate `fact`, because no matter what `fact` is bound to (whether the original or the decorated function), `helper` is never rebound.

Answer (score 0):

Or just do this:

```
def R_F(n):
    if n<=2:
        return 1
    else:
        return R_F(n-1)+R_F(n-2)

R_FCOST = time_cost(R_F)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).